# Google Calendar Sync duplicate events

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, google-calendar

I have the following setup:

- Google account
- Outlook account
- Laptop with Outlook 2010 Standard and Calendar Sync running
- [Calendar sync](http://www.pppindia.com/calendar-sync/) is set to autosyncrhonize at regular time intervals. Following settings are used : two-way sync, delete duplicates

The problem I encounter manifests itself randomly in the following way:

- I create an event in Google
- At the next scheduled synchronization, the Calendar Sync copies the event to outlook calendar
- At the 2nd scheduled synchronization, the Calendar Sync copies the event back to google creating first duplicate (2 identical events in total)
- At the 3rd scheduled synchronization, the Calendar Sync copies the event back to google creating second duplicate (3 identical events in total)
- At the 4th scheduled synchronization, the Calendar Sync copies the event back to google creating second duplicate (4 identical events in total)
- ... and so on

The process may continue indefinitely making the calendar pretty unreadable. Results often looks like this:

[image]

For "All-day" events it looks like this:

[image]

I have made following observations:

- Events subjected to the problem seem to be random
- This happens approximately for 1 event every week, though may be 2-3 or 0 sometimes
- The duplication will continue indefinitely, clogging up my calendar until I do one of the following: A. Delete all duplicates from Google and delete the same event from Outlook. B. Delete all the duplicates from Google and rename the subjected device in outlook
- Checking "Delete Duplicates" checkbox in Calendar Sync has no effect
- Changing autosync scheduling interval makes no effect on the bug
- I am running version 3.0.6.6c3 though I have experienced the same issue in earlier versions too
- This may happen to normal events (timed) as well as "all-day" events
- Synchronizing using login/password method or using Google API does not make any difference, problem still persists
- There are never any duplicates in outlook
- I cannot confirm if the only events that are subject to this issue are the ones created in Google. I will keep observing for now

Following too screenshots may give a better summary of the program settings:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months of tolerating this bug and ~2 weeks of trying to find a solution I eventually gave up and switched to a different software:
[CalendarSyncPlus](https://calendarsyncplus.codeplex.com/)

I hope no one will consider this to be an advertising. Both programs perform effectively the same set of functions.

[CalendarSync](http://www.pppindia.com/calendar-sync/) in my case has a bug described in my original question (which I could not tolerate any more)

CalendarSyncPlus causes my outlook to freeze 1 or 2 times a day, but that I can tolerate.

I hope this answer will be helpful to those experiencing similar issues

Answer (score 4):

Looks like "Calendar Sync" cannot correctly sync an event with some specific set of properties. When it copies it to Google, the copy ends up being imperfect, and at the next sync, it sees it as a different event.

It's quite likely that copies actually end up imperfect in many cases due to differences in functionality between Outlook and Google, and Sync has an internal database of such cases to handle them in a sensible way. Then it's just that it doesn't (yet) know of this particular case (maybe it results from some recent change in either or the products, or some specific settings that you have that result in some automatic actions).

Whichever is the case, you should contact the program's developer and provide them the exact copy of the Outlook event that triggers this bug and its Google Calendar "copy".